# How to loop a VideoView element in MainActivity.java?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I've written an application which plays a video until you tap the screen and it exits.  A basic screensaver essentially. 
The app will launch and play the video however it stops on the last frame rather than loops.

Code from my MainActivity.java below

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.hab2);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoView.start();
        videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                finish();
            }
        });    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle easily if you use MediaPlayer

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Apologies, I'm relatively new to this.  How would this fit in with the code I posted?